# How to intercept parent http request into dependency library : spring application

Tags: spring, http, request, dependencies, intercept

I am working on application which uses library for authentification.
I want to capture/intercept few header information of HTTP request during user's authentification. In the library, I create a restController but I have never captured the request.

Postman request: `http://localhost:8080/myApp/user/login/authenticate`

response Status: HTTP Status 404

> 14:16:11.959 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
>   - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
>
> 14:16:27.074 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher -
>   Checking match of request : '/user/login/authenticate'; against
>   '/rest/olta/**'
>
> 14:16:27.074 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher -
>   Checking match of request : '/user/login/authenticate'; against
>   '/rest/errors/**/**'
>
> 14:16:27.074 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher -
>   Checking match of request : '/user/login/authenticate'; against
>   '/rest/parameter/**/**'
>
> 14:16:27.074 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher -
>   Checking match of request : '/user/login/authenticate'; against
>   '/rest/user/authenticate'
>
> 14:16:27.074 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher -
>   Checking match of request : '/user/login/authenticate'; against
>   '/rest/isUp'
>
> 14:16:27.074 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy -
>   /user/login/authenticate has no matching filters
>
> 14:16:27.074 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet
>   with name 'dispatcher' processing POST request for
>   [/myApp/user/login/authenticate]
>
> 14:16:27.074 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
>   - Looking up handler method for path /user/login/authenticate
>
> 14:16:27.075 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
>   - Did not find handler method for [/user/login/authenticate]
>
> 14:16:27.075 [http-8080-4] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for
>   HTTP request with URI [/myApp/user/login/authenticate] in
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
>
> 14:16:27.075 [http-8080-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully
>   completed request

Parent application's web.xml:

```
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
             version="2.5">
      <display-name>myApp WebApp</display-name>

      <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
      </filter>

      <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>
      <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
          classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
      </context-param>

      <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
      </listener>

      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
          <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
          </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

My Controller in dependency library:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user/login")
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(value = "authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<User> authenticate(@RequestParam("username") String username,
            @RequestParam("password") String password) {
...
}
```

Comment: You are using Spring Security, then why do you work with a controller. Let Spring Security handle all that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ M. Deinum. In my parent app all is ok.  If I remove the controller, how can I do to intercept this request into my library ? By creating a filter ?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do/achieve.

Comment: I want just to intercept http request when user clic on login.

Comment: But for what purpose... If it is only logging, then just create a filter, if you want to do something else with it, you might want to integrate with Spring security. Hence my question what is the purpose.

Comment: I want to check if the authorization request header contains the good credentials to authenticate with a server.  The library should be used by other applications.

Comment: That should be in the filter that actually does the check.

Comment: Here is my filter in library:                                                
        <bean id="noEntryPoint"
  class="com.glm.sso.filter.UnauthorizedEntryPoint">
 </bean>

 <bean id="mySpaFilter"
  class="com.glm.sso.filter.SsoCustomFilter" />
          <security:http pattern="/*"
  entry-point-ref="noEntryPoint">
  <security:custom-filter
   position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="mySpaFilter" />
 </security:http>                                                                                                            SsoCustomFilter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot intercept any request... I am asking what is wrong ?